# An Enquiry Concerning the "reward function" for a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

**The Statement of the Problem:**

Consider a Markov chain with state space

$$ S = \{1, 2, 3 \} $$

and probability transition matrix

$$ P = \left(
        \begin{matrix}
        .3 & .7 &  0 \\
        .4 & .4 & .2 \\
         0 & .7 & .3 \\
        \end{matrix} \right)
$$

Find $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^{n}X(k) $$ where $X(k)$ is the state at time $k$.

**The Solution:**

Let $g(j)$ be the "reward function" for $j \in S$. Then, since this MC is irreducible,

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^{n}g \left[X(k)\right] = \sum_{j \in S}g(j)\pi_j $$

where $\pi_j$ is the long-run proportion of time that the process will be in state $j$.

So, we have $\pi = \left(\frac{4}{13}, \frac{7}{13}, \frac{2}{13}\right)$. No problem. All I need to determine is $g(j)$ and sum the three $\pi$'s weighted by their rewards. Now, *for some reason*, the solution states (without qualification, so it must be "obvious") that

$$ g(j) = j . $$

Well, ok, that certainly makes the computation easy; but I can't, for the life of me, see why this is the case, i.e. that $g(j) = j$ (I suppose one could say that each state is a "fixed point" of $g$). Can someone please shine a light on this for me?

Comment: The reward function is *defined* to be $g(j)=j$ since the value you’re accumulating in the sum is the state number at step $n$.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm misunderstanding something. Why can we define it to be so? I mean, what's even the point of this "reward" function if it's just the identity function? We could just put $j$ in the sum instead of $g(j)$ if this is how it's defined. Furthermore, why would the "reward" given for the time spent in state $j$ be equal to its state number, which is essentially just an arbitrary index?

Comment: Fill in the missing step: $lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n g(X(k)) = \sum_{j\in S} g(j)\pi_j$. The idea here is to use a general result about expected reward to compute interesting things about the MC. In this case it’s used to find the “average” state that the MC is in. Another example is to set $g(1)=0$ and $1$ otherwise, and then modify the MC to make $1$ a trapping state. You can then use a general result about expected reward to compute the expected number of steps to reach state $1$ from any other given state.

Comment: Oh! I see... it's sort of like an "indicator function." And, actually, the "missing step" is what I meant to write in the first place (I will edit to reflect that). Ok, this makes more sense now. Thanks!